# Best possible environment for Ruby and Rails on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, windows

I normally develop for Ruby and Ruby on Rails on a mac, but in my workplace we use Windows. We are starting to do some stuff in Ruby at work, so I am trying to set up an environment... and it is a pain in the ass.

I just installed ruby with the win automatic installer thingy, but I have to run a special version of the cmd to run ruby scripts.

In OSX I do  everything with Textmate and Terminal, and I love that I can run ruby scripts from Textmate.

In win I have to go back and forth between Notepadd ++ and  the shitty command line, and run scripts from there.

Is there any chance to replicate my OSX environment's functionalities in Windows 7? I am specially interested on being able to run RUby scripts from a lightweight IDE.

Comment: use virtual machine with linux distro

Comment: Do you think ruby on Windows is that bad? I would use Linux and dump windows, but the company uses MS and I have to stick with that...

Comment: using windows as a development system for RoR is a very *bizzare* idea. because many gems (hpricot, nokogiri, etc) require unix tools for building.

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely and ultimately best IDE for Rails for me is [RubyMine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyMine). Never seen better integration between framework / IDE. Still, that probably means I've got little experience with high-level frameworks, but it is indeed astonishingly good.

Comment: Completely agree, I've been using Rubymine on Windows 7 for 2 years now and it's the fashiz.. very very good IDE

Answer (score 0):

[aswer edited/improved]

Vagrant is a very good option for the problem: manuel.manuelles.nl/blog/2013/07/23/…  samora.me/2012/11/finally-there-is-cure-for-ruby-on-rails.html

Also, i suppose there is this way to use Notepad++ to run the Ruby scripts: compinfopro.com/run-ruby-program-and-compile-sources

Another option available on Windows OS is to use the JRUby intepreter that comes integrated with the NetBeans IDE: netbeans.org/community/articles/ruby-with-netbeans.html

For Rails development on Windows, RailsInstaller could also be useful
http://railsinstaller.org/

Comment: your answer will have to include more then that.

Comment: Would you mind to explain what do you think need to be included in my answer? For example the reason why i think rails installer is a good option for Ruby development on Windows (which is basiclly the easy setup process)? links for tutorials and/or documentation of rails installer?

By the way, Vagrant is another very good option for the problem:

http://manuel.manuelles.nl/blog/2013/07/23/developing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows/

http://www.samora.me/2012/11/finally-there-is-cure-for-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: and i suppose there is this way to use Notepad++ to run the Ruby scripts: http://compinfopro.com/run-ruby-program-and-compile-sources/

Comment: another option available on Windows OS is to use the JRUby intepreter that comes integrated with the NetBeans IDE: https://netbeans.org/community/articles/ruby-with-netbeans.html

Comment: add that to your answer please.